# Good FPS in Editor But not on devices(Google Cardboard), How to increase FPS?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, lag, google-cardboard

I'm working on Google Cardboard Game. I have 5-10 sprites, a terrain with 15-30 pieces of bush on it(single bushes like grass),15 trees(low poly with <64 vertices),a Camera (provided by GVR Sdk).

On the Editor Framerate is good. But when I test it on my Galaxy S6, the FPS is low as 10-20(I've attached a script that gets Framerate on a Text).
Any optimization tip?

Here is detail of stats in Unity Editor:

CPU: main 6.0ms

FPS: 160(average)

Batches:117

Tris: 6.1k

Verts: 3.3k

Comment: Check Android section of [this page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html) to profile your game while playing from android phone. N.B: you need Pro version of Unity to use profiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you had lot of times used methods "GameObject.Find()" and "gameobject.GetComponent()" in the runtime.
**This is most common issue of unity developers.**

**Better do not use them at runtime at all!** Only inside of **awake** or in **start** methods.

You need to make all needed GetComponent<> inside of awake or start methods and assign result to some global variables. After -- just use this variable in runtime.

This will really increase your game speed on the mobile devices.

Comment: Which alternative can I use for GetComponent<>?

Comment: I've checked there is not a huge number of GetComponent<> methods in my code. But Google VR sdk have number of them. How to get rid of them(is there any alternative).

Comment: You need to make all needed  GetComponent<> on awake or start methods and assign result to some global variable. After -- just use this variable in runtime.

Comment: My answer in this thread gives an example of how to use those methods in `Start()` instead of runtime: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38905877/unity-run-code-on-touch-with-a-ui-image-c-sharp/38906097#38906097

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your device is not overheating, might seem obvious but you can't always tell when it is on your face (I also own an S6).

Also, make sure you are not in energy saver mode, sounds dumb but I fell for it already ;)

Among the huge amount of things that can ruin the performance of a game on smartphone are:

- Make sure you don't have a script doing too much work in Update (especially Instanciate()/Destroy()
- Don't move static objects, just don't
- Make sure you don't use high resolution textures (in my small experience > 512x512 is, that they are squared and have a resolution that is a power of two

As a side note, GetComponents can be an issue, the alternative was already posted by @Andrew, just use GetComponent in the Start()/Awake() method and store them to use them later on.

Comment: You really helped me.... Plz explain me a bit about Instanciate and destroy.. My game really needs them. What should I do?

Comment: I have used Instantiates in Co Routines with a duration of 5 secs not in Update function. And I have used destroy function on click that may occur after 5-10 secs. Is that an issue for performance? If is what should I do??

Comment: In your situation this is *not* an issue then. Instanciating and destroying may become an issue when you call it too frequently, such as in the Update() function, which is a very common beginner mistake.